# CSS transform animation syntax style

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, stylelint

For a situation like this:

```
@keyframes rotateMe {
   0% { 
     transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
   }
}
```

Stylelint flags the `0deg` as not needing the unit.  I know for things like `0px` to leave off the `px`, but I'm wondering if the transform would still work without the `deg` on the `0`.

Comment: Simple answer is yes. Units only make sense when you have >0 of them. 0px = 0deg = 0elephants, it's all just 0.

Comment: As @TedSales says, yes. But animations on transforms are very prone to give problems if the 2 (or more) transforms differ even slightly. So it is always a good idea to make the as similar as possible. Since the final keyframe has deg, just put deg on the initial state just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @vals that's what I was thinking.